# Stored procedure to Linked server with parameters - Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I'm trying to create stored procedure to **Linked server**, which input parameter @ServerName is the name of Linked Server i use.
In this procedure I also Declare parameter which value I want to get from Dynamic SQL Query and line.

> CREATE PROC sp_Version @ServerName varchar(30)
>   as
>   Declare @Ver varchar(10)
>       exec ('select @Ver from openquery(' + @ServerName + ',     ''SELECT SUBSTRING  (@@VERSION, 22, 7) = @Ver''')

When I execute my sp i get an error saying:

> "Must declare the scalar variable "@Ver"."

Could you please help me?

Comment: For user stored procedures, it is not a good practice to use `sp_`, you are declaring @ver for this server, procedure expects to see variable in linked server

Comment: "procedure expects to see variable in linked server" 
what you mean by that is by "Declare @Ver varchar(10)"
I declared variable for my local server, but not for linked server or sth like that?

Comment: Your variable `@Ver` isn't accessible inside your dynamic SQL because it is executed as a separate scope (with the EXEC). You should use the procedure sp_executesql and output the `@ver` value as an Output parameter.

Comment: Don't use `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedures, especially not one with a name as potentially clash-worthy as `sp_version`. [See also](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). Also, the `SUBSTRING` approach is flawed -- on my server I get `2017 (R`, which is probably not what you intended. Look at things like `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')`. And as others have mentioned, you can't remote variables like this -- look at `INSERT .. EXEC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across this situation a couple of times. Try this:

```
CREATE PROC sp_Version @ServerName varchar(30)
as
Declare @Ver varchar(10)

DECLARE @SqlCommand nvarchar(MAX)

SET @SqlCommand = 'SELECT @Ver2 = SUBSTRING (@@VERSION, 22, 7) '

DECLARE @sp_executesql VARCHAR(100)
SET @sp_executesql = @ServerName + '.master.sys.sp_executesql'
EXEC @sp_executesql @SqlCommand, N'@Ver2 nvarchar(10) out', @Ver out
SELECT @Ver
```

Comment: i get an error:
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure usp_Version, Line 17
Could not find stored procedure ''.

Comment: Does it say which stored procedure it can't find? In my example I have a sp_Version, you created usp_Version (with a leading 'u')?

Comment: yes, because i'have been said that "sp_" naming is a bad practice, because users cannot say if this procedure was system or user proc

Comment: yeah, you're right. I usually use usp as well, dont know why I haven't use in this example. Anyway: does it say which stored procedure it cant find?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your aim is with the value of @Ver, perhaps an `OUTPUT` parameter? If so, then the syntax would be:

```
CREATE PROC GetVersion @ServerName varchar(30), @Ver nvarchar(500) OUTPUT AS

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT @dVer = Version' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'                ' + QUOTENAME('Server=' + @ServerName + ';Trusted_Connection=YES;','''') + ',' +NCHAR(10) +
               N'                ''SELECT @@VERSION AS Version'');';

    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dVer nvarchar(500) OUTPUT', @dVer = @Ver OUTPUT;


GO

DECLARE @ver varchar(500)

EXEC GetVersion 'YourServerName', @ver OUTPUT;

PRINT @ver;
GO

DROP PROC GetVersion;
```

Note, firstly, as suggested I didn't use the `sp_` prefix. I've also used `sp_executesql`  instead of simply `EXEC` (this is generally better practice, as you can parametrise your dynamic SQL then, as i have done), and `QUOTENAME` to try and avoid injection.